# How to detect webbrowser is downloading data from target server when click an element in C#

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

Here is the situation: I use `WebBrowser` in the program, I want detect is the browser downloaded data from target server when click a html element on it.

This is what I want do:

```
HtmlElement element = browser.GetOneElement
element.InvokeMember("click");
if(will download data from the server?)
{
    //do something
}
else
{
    //do other thing
}
```

Currently, my solution is to set a flag to note is downloading, and extended `OnProgressChanged` of the `WebBrowser` control, set the flag as true there.

Here is the code:

```
    private bool _isInteractive;
    public bool IsInteractive
    {
        set 
        {
            _isInteractive = true;
        }
        get
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            return _isInteractive;
        }
    }
```

Then using it like this:

```
HtmlElement element = browser.GetOneElement
browser.IsInteractive = false;
element.InvokeMember("click");
if(browser.IsInteractive)
{
    //do something
}
else
{
    //do other thing
}
```

But I think it's not so good, even sucks. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

How about the [`WebBrowser.IsBusy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.isbusy.aspx) property?

Comment: here is comments from source code Gets a value indicating whether the System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser control is currently loading a new document. I think it will be download data first then load the document,right? so we should wait for a while after the click, then detect IsBusy, how long should be waiting?

Comment: PS:it will be set as false when loading completed

Comment: @Yunfei.Xiao no you should not wait, and definitely not a random amount which you guess the browser needs. I don't know what you're exactly trying to accomplish. You want to detect whether the browser is downloading data, right? That is "loading a new document", so IsBusy will be true then.

Comment: yes, you are right. it will not turns to True immediately after we click.
you say using like this :

    HtmlElement element = browser.GetOneElement
    element.InvokeMember("click");
    if(browser.IsBusy)
    {
       //do something
    }
    else
    {
       //do other thing
    }

Comment: Will the OnDocumentCompleted event be any use in this situation, rather than waiting / polling for IsBusy to change?

Comment: OnDocumentCompleted will not been raised if we did not send request to the host, so we need waiting / polling something, right?